# При маленьком размере шрифта получаются вот такие дефекты, как такое исправить?

Tags: sh

Так выглядит отображение шрифтов при размере 17:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
!#include ".Xresources.d/rxvt-unicode"
#include ".Xresources.d/colors"
xft.dpi:96
Xft.antialias:true
!Xft.rgba:rgb
Xft.hinting:full
Xft.hintstyle:hintslight
Xft.autohint:true
Xft.lcdfilter:lcddefault
URxvt.scrollBar:true
URxvt.scrollBar_right:true
URxvt*scrollstyle:plain
URxvt*scrollColor:#aaaaaa
!#URxvt*scrollColor:#aaaaaa
URxvt*jumpScroll:true
URxvt*skipScroll:true
URxvt.letterSpace:0
URxvt.underlineURLs:false
URxvt*saveLines:13000
URxvt*skipBuiltinGlyphs:true
URxvt.internalBorder:8
URxvt*cursorBlink:true
URxvt.secondaryScroll:0
URxvt.boldFont:
URxvt.secondaryWheel:1
URxvt*lineSpace:0
!URxvt*title:term
!URxvt*font:-xos4-terminus-medium-r-normal-*-18-*-*-72-*-*-*-1
!URxvt.font:xft:monospace:pixelsize=14
!URxvt*font:xft:source pro regular:9
!URxvt*font:xft:monospace:9
!URxvt*font:xft:bront:11
!URxvt*font:xft:dejavu:11
!URxvt.font:xft:DejaVu Sans Mono:7
URxvt*font: xft:Terminus:pixelsize=17
URxvt*depth:32
!URxvt*fading: 10
!URxvt*fadeColor:white
URxvt.inputMethod:ibus
URxvt.preeditType:OverTheSpot
URxvt.perl-ext-common:  resize-font
URxvt.keysym.Shift-Up:command:\033]720;1\007
URxvt.keysym.Shift-Down:command:\033]721;1\007
URxvt.keysym.C-plus:resize-font:bigger
URxvt.keysym.C-minus:resize-font:smaller
URxvt.resize-font.step:2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было раскомментировать ту строку, что я подчеркнул и закомментировать строку на которую указал стрелочкой

[image]